# Filtering AWS CloudWatch raw log events by multiple values / AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Given the following query on CloudWatch that extracts logs with messages including "entry 1456" *(where 1456 is an ID)* how should I extend this to take multiple IDs and what is the corresponding CLI command?

```
fields  @message
| filter @message like "entry 1456"
| limit 10
```

To clarify I'd like to filter with multiple IDs, for instance "like 1456|1257|879". But not sure of the format of regex in such case.

And I assume the corresponding CLI command will be sth like:

```
aws logs filter-log-events 
--log-group-name group_name
--app
--filter-pattern ........
```

Just want to make sure of the best way to formulate this.

Comment: You might want to checkout https://github.com/jorgebastida/awslogs

Answer (score 11):

The syntax would be:

```
fields  @message
| filter @message like /entry [1456|1257]/
| limit 10
```

You could also parse the logline first and extract the value, like this:

```
fields  @message
| parse @message /.*entry (?<id>\d+).*/
| filter id in [1257, 1456]
| limit 10
```

Now for the CLI, you would not use the **filter-log-events**, but the [start-query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/start-query.html) and [get-query-results](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/logs/get-query-results.html).

Comment: Thanks. The first works with parentheses () `fields  @message| filter @message like /entry (1456|1257)/`

Comment: Yes, just echoing OmaymaS's comment here. `[]` is a regex character group, you want `()` for a capture group

Answer (score 2):

Just for visibility and copy/paste ability the current correct syntax is :

```
fields @message
| filter @message like /entry (1457|1458)/
| limit 20
```